How to integrate highcharts-vue with Quasar app
Im trying to integrate highcharts-vue with my Quasar app. I think I have followed all the instructions, but the chart is not shown. I do get a bunch of errors in console but Im unable to pin-point the problem. I have a boot file called chart.ts created as well.
Here is the playground.
It seems that the highcharts component is not correctly registered but other than stuff in boot file, I dont know what else to do.
Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?
The initial page is blank due to highcharts errors.

Hi @Boss Man, The link to the playground doesn't work or is private. Can you fix that?

I'm pretty sure it's this issue here, the root cause being default Quasar's use of Vite 2.  As the Quasar dev suggests, follow the upgrade guide to use latest Vite 5 with Quasar which should fix the issue.

@ppotaczek It is working. I just opened it. But I have noticed that sometimes it doesnt work.

@yoduh you are right. After following the upgrade steps, I see the chart. If you want to add your comment as an answer I can accept it.
